# How can I scrape this table more efficiently?

Tags: python, screen-scraping

Okay, I have built a program to scrape yahoo finance.  I want the historical prices of a certain stock.  I then want it to be written to an excel spreadsheet.  It is doing everything the way it's supposed to, but it gives me ALL of the data on the whole page! I need just the data in the table.  Thanks.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import requests

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

playerdatasaved=""
soup = make_soup("https://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=USO+Historical+Prices")
for record in soup.findAll('tr'):
playerdata=""
for data in record.findAll('td'):
   playerdata=playerdata+","+data.text
if len(playerdata)!=0:
    playerdatasaved = playerdatasaved + "\n" + playerdata[1:]

header="Open,Close,High,Low"
file = open(os.path.expanduser("Uso.csv"),"wb")
file.write(bytes(header, encoding="ascii",errors='ignore'))
file.write(bytes(playerdatasaved, encoding="ascii",errors='ignore'))

print(playerdatasaved)
```

Comment: Didn't you ask this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240961/how-do-i-scrape-just-the-table) a few hours ago on another account? It's not appreciated by Stack Overflow to make multiple accounts to repeatedly ask the same question.

Comment: If you messed something up in the question, you can edit it instead (there's a button at the bottom of the question to do that)

Comment: I did, but it was not answered, and I really need it to be answered.  I understand that everyone is a coding god, and are bothered to come down to my level, but I really don't have time for all that... I just need this figured out.  to answer the next person, I think the messup is the link.  Try using this link:

Comment: https://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=USO+Historical+Prices

Comment: @Jake it *was* answered... if you weren't happy with the answer, you should have commented and worked it out, okay?

Comment: there was a lengthy conversation, he deleted it.  It really wasn't, but thanks.

Comment: @JonClements: doesn't OP frankly admit to having two accounts here?

Answer (score 0):

To get the table of data:

```
soup = make_soup("https://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=USO+Historical+Prices")
table = [[cell.text for row in soup.findAll('tr')] for cell in soup.findAll('td')]
```

To write out the table of data to a file:

```
import csv

with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(table)
```